# Interstitial ADS Closing

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I need some help the problem is that when Interstitial ads open and when it closes it unloads the loaded ad from the variable I am using for displaying Interstitial ADS , my question is can I stop it from unloading the ads ? If yes then how can I do it?

Comment: This is normal... After the Ad is closed, you need to download a new one and when it is ready, you display it again

Answer (score 0):

This is normal.

Same add can be displayed only once. After it is closed, you must request a new one. You can use same `InterstitialAd` object to request a new AD. However, you really must load a new one.

You can create an AdListener and check when the add is closed. This way, you can request a new one.

In [AdMob's DOC](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial) page, you can find some examples:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("AD UNIT ID");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                  .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                  .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```